# How to create this particular fractal pattern in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to make an array of zeros and ones in this particular fractal pattern:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The actual array should be 100 x 100. The pattern should start from the middle (x,y) coordinate, and expand to look like the pattern (using loops).

So far, I have only managed to make a pattern that looks like a '+' sign. I am not sure how to continue it.

This is my code so far:

```matlab
n = zeros(16); % using 16x16 array for practice
x = length(n)/2;
y = length(n)/2;
z = length(n) - 1;

xso = length(n)/2; % x axis south movement
xno = length(n)/2; % x axis north movement
yea = length(n)/2; % y axis east movement
ywe = length(n)/2; % y axis west movement

for i = 1:1:z
        newyea = move('east', x, yea);
        n(x, newyea) = 1;
        yea = newyea;

        newywe = move('west', x, ywe);
        n(x, newywe) = 1;
        ywe = newywe;

        newxso = move('south', xso, y);
        n(newxso, y) = 1;
        xso = newxso;

        newxno = move('north', xno, y);
        n(newxno, y) = 1;
        xno = newxno;
end
```

I also have a user defined function:

```matlab
function newval = move(dir, x, y)

switch dir
    case 'east'
        newval = y + 1;
    case 'west'
        newval = y - 1;
    case 'south'
        newval = x + 1;
    case 'north'
        newval = x - 1;
end
```

Comment: You should be able to upload an image. It only shows the link in the question if your rep is too low, but someone else will be able to edit your question and include the image into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there were no restrictions given on the appearance of the loop, I would propose the below solution. But, before, let's have a look at your given example:

[image: Given example]

Either you should restrict the desired dimension `d` to be odd, i.e. `d = 11, 13, 15, ...` or you should specify, how the pattern should be continued in case of an even dimension `d`, like here `d = 12`. For my solution, I decided to rely on the dimension `d` to be odd.

Here's the code:

```matlab
d = 15;                 % Dimension

A = zeros(d);           % Initialize output array A

c = (d + 1) / 2;        % Calculate center index (row, column)

A(:, c) = 1;            % Add: Cross 
A(c, :) = 1;

J = 0;                  % Auxiliary index
for I = (c+2):2:d       % For every second row (or column) from center to border
  J = J + 1;             
  l = 4 * J - 1;        % Calculate length of line to draw
  s = c - (l-1)/2;      % Calculate start point of line
  e = c + (l-1)/2;      % Calculate end point of line
  A(I, s:e) = 1;        % Add: "South" line
  A(s:e, I) = 1;        % Add: "East" line
  A(c - 2*J, s:e) = 1;  % Add: "North" line
  A(s:e, c - 2*J) = 1;  % Add: "West" line
end

figure(1);              % Show image
imagesc(A);
```

Output for `d = 15` (to compare to given example):

[image: Output for d = 15]

Output for `d = 99`:

[image: Output for d = 99]

Hope that helps!

If you have some more stricter limitations on the for loop, let me/us know. Then, I will try to modify my code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! There are no stricter limitations for the loop, this helps a lot! Cheers man <3